# What product is used in OSX to edit word or openoffice documents and also works with PDF?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

I want to be able to copy portions of PDF file and paste into another document like MS Word format document. The important thing is that any portion that is copied must preserver original formatting fonts etc. when it is pasted into my document. So what product is out there on the writing side and what product is out there on the PDF side?

Answer (score 2):

Preserving the layout and appearance from text in a PDF when copying it to anther text processing tool is almost an impossible task, both on OSX and Windows.

I'd suggest two things:

- **Export to .rtf**. In Windows using Acrobat Professional you can export as .rtf, which can be opened by Microsoft Word (among others) and is (sometimes) a close approximation of the layout and still allows for editing the text.
  On OSX there appears to be tools that allows exporting to .rtf as well, like this one: [File Juicer](http://echoone.com/filejuicer/pdf-to-word) (never actually tried or used it). You can then open the .rtf file using Word, OpenOffice, etc.
- **screenshot** - However, if post-editing text is not of your concerns, I'd go for a screenshot from the PDF that you paste into whatever editor you are using.

Answer (score 1):

To edit Word Documents you usually use Microsoft Word.
Pages, LibreOffice and OpenOffice can open them too with some minor compatibility issues.

To edit OpenOffice Documents you can use OpenOffice or LibreOffice.

ANd forr editing PDF files couldnt you even use Preview for that.
At least that is what this article says: [link](http://osxdaily.com/2009/09/12/pdf-editors-for-mac-os-x-whats-the-best-way-to-edit-a-pdf-on-your-mac/)

i hope this helps, if you have any other concerns tell me

Answer (score 0):

Copying and pasting text from a PDF in Apple Preview, and then pasting it into another document, works well under some circumstances. It generally works better than trying the same thing in Adobe Reader X.

Answer (score 0):

For editing and modifying PDFs, Apple Preview has some functions for that, but if you want to do much more, try Smile Software's [PDFPen](http://smilesoftware.com/PDFpen/index.html) and [PDFPenPro](http://smilesoftware.com/PDFpenPro/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

[NeoOffice](http://www.neooffice.org/neojava/en/index.php) is a shareware "fork" of OpenOffice.org and LibreOffice that is custom-tailored to the Mac user interface and better integrated with Mac OS X than either OpenOffice or LibreOffice. Of course it also makes PDFs and works with OpenDocument format (.odt). I highly recommend NeoOffice. I have been using it and making donations to support its development for the last seven years.